# Use a class on azure and on a other app: monitoring dilemma

Tags: c#, logging, azure, console-application, monitoring

First, I'm a beginner with C# and I haven't lot of programmer habit.

I want use the same class on windows azure and on a Console app.
For example this one :

```
public static class Conversion
{
    public static void Convert(string fileName)
    {
        // ...
        if (error)
            Console.WriteLine("It is a error in Conversion.Convert(string).");
        // ...
        Console.WriteLine("Conversion success !");
    }
}
```

But, display on a console in azure isn't very usefull. I have think to create an interface and 2 implementations of it.

```
public interface ILog
{
    void Write(string str);
    void WriteLinge(string str);
}
```

And

```
public static class LogAzure : ILog
{
    public static void WriteLine(string str)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(str);
    }

}


public static class LogConsole : ILog
{
    public static void WriteLine(string str)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

So in my convert methode I have to use ILog.WriteLine().

**Questions :**
First - and the more important - is it a good idea/practice ?

If yes :
How know that I'm in Azure or not ?  ([RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.isavailable) ??)
How use LogAzure or LogConsole ? (with argument on my method ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Trace in both cases.  Configure the console app to use [ConsoleTraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener.aspx) and the azure version to use the [Azure diagnostics](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/)

Comment: Ok, it work fine. I'm a begginer in C# and I don't know all this little trick, but I see that it provide a usefull API ! :) Thx.